# Comparing XML string with different formats

Tags: c#, xml, formatting

I need to compare 2 xml strings where the formatting may be different. The approach is to use the `XmlWriterSettings` to format both strings and compare the formatted result:

```
public static class XmlHelper
{
    public static string FormatXml(string xml)
    {
        try
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            var element = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = "  ";
            settings.NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine;
            settings.NewLineOnAttributes = false;
            settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;

            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, settings))
                element.Save(xmlWriter);

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Unable to format XML: '" + xml + "'", ex);
            return xml;
        }
    }

    public static bool CompareXml(string xmlA, string xmlB)
    {
        if (xmlA == null && xmlB == null)
            return true;
        if (xmlA == null || xmlB == null)
            return false;

        var xmlFormattedA = FormatXml(xmlA);
        var xmlFormattedB = FormatXml(xmlB);

        return xmlFormattedA.Equals(xmlFormattedB, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Do you see any problems with that approach?
- Is there a simpler way to accomplish that kind of comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for *xml compare c#* produces countless results so I just review this code without suggesting anything alternative.

---

> ```
> settings.IndentChars = "  ";
> ```

I find `new string(' ', 3)` is easier to understand then three (?) spaces.

---

> ```
>     if (xmlA == null && xmlB == null)
>         return true;
> ```

This is questionable. I'd say it should be `false`.

---

> ```
> var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
> settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
> ```

Don't you like object initializers?

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. a) agree (they are actual 2 spaces ;)) b) Yes, that is questionable (and it is very unlikely that the case occurs someday)... however, `string.Equals(null, null)` is true, therefore I think the result should be true as well . c) I like it too... changed the impl. :)